# Django many-to-many model DRF

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-orm

I have the following model structure:

```
class Project(models.Model):
  author = models.ManyToManyField(Account)
  name = models.CharField(max_length=40, default='NewBook')

class Account(AbstractBaseUser):
  email = models.EmailField(unique=True)
  username = models.CharField(max_length=40, unique=True)
  first_name = models.CharField(max_length=40, blank=True)
  last_name = models.CharField(max_length=40, blank=True)
  tagline = models.CharField(max_length=140, blank=True)
  is_admin = models.BooleanField(default=False)
  created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
  updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
  objects = AccountManager()
  USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
  REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['username']
```

My view looks like this:

```
class ProjectViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
  queryset = Project.objects.order_by('-name')
  serializer_class = ProjectSerializer

  def perform_create(self, serializer):
    instance = serializer.save(author=self.request.user)
    return super(ProjectViewSet, self).perform_create(serializer)
```

After calling the view function, a classifier gets created in the database. But after that, I get the following error:

> TypeError: 'Account' object is not iterable

The error gets thrown in this line:

```
instance = serializer.save(author=self.request.user)
```

Anyone how can help me with this?

Comment: You need to show us the full stacktrace, we couldn't tell how does the error happen.

Comment: Here is the full stacktrace @ShangWang http://pastebin.com/i0mqP5X1

Comment: What does your serializer looks like ?

Comment: Here is my serializer @Linovia http://pastebin.com/f6a2tKvY

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two problems here:

1. Showing [nested relationships](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/#nested-relationships) for M2M field:

> If the field is used to represent a to-many relationship, you should add the `many=True` flag to the serializer field.

So you need to add `many=True` to `AccountSerializer`:

```
author = AccountSerializer(read_only=True, required=False, many=True)
```

2. A [writable nested serializer](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/#writable-nested-serializers):

> By default nested serializers are `read-only`. If you want to support write-operations to a nested serializer field you'll need to create `create()` and/or `update()` methods in order to explicitly specify how the child relationships should be saved.

So if you look at the example and the documentation it seems that you need to implement `create` or `update` method.

Comment: Thanks, the creation of a Project is working now. Another question: How can I add an author to my Project? Do I have to call .PUT(..) on my frontend?

Comment: You can call `PATCH` method on the frontend and then write `update()` method in serializer to handle that.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set `many=True` when dealing with multiple relation - either a m2m or a reversed FK:

```
author = AccountSerializer(read_only=True, required=False, many=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

Since your Author field is many to many, you will need to override the create method on your serializer.

```
def create(self, validated_data):
     author = validated_data.pop(author, None)
     project = Project.objects.save(validated_data)
     if author:
         project.author.add(author)
```

You will also probably need to set the update method on the serializer, the behavior here can be tricky so make sure you test and make sure the behavior is what you expect.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, my previous answer, though could be an issue, isn't the root cause of the actual crash.

When calling the serializer, you set:

```
instance = serializer.save(author=self.request.user)
```

However, author is a `ManyToManyField` which means you should call the serializer as:

```
instance = serializer.save(author=[self.request.user])
```

NB: you still require the many=True on the serializer's author field.

Answer (score 0):

Please check...

your **model.py**

```
class Account(AbstractBaseUser):
  email = models.EmailField(unique=True)
  username = models.CharField(max_length=40, unique=True)
  first_name = models.CharField(max_length=40, blank=True)
  last_name = models.CharField(max_length=40, blank=True)
  tagline = models.CharField(max_length=140, blank=True)
  is_admin = models.BooleanField(default=False)
  created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
  updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
  objects = AccountManager()
  USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
  REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['username']


class Project(models.Model):
      author = models.ManyToManyField(Account)
      name = models.CharField(max_length=40, default='NewBook')
```

your **serializer.py**

```
class ProjectSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    author = AccountSerializer(read_only=True, required=False)

    class Meta:
        model = Project
        fields = ('id', 'author', 'name')
        read_only_fields = ('id')

    def get_validation_exclusions(self, *args, **kwargs):
        exclusions = super(ProjectSerializer, self).get_validation_exclusions()
        return exclusions + ['author']
```

and finally your **view.py** is

```
class ProjectViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
  queryset = Project.objects.order_by('-name')
  serializer_class = ProjectSerializer

  def perform_create(self, serializer):
    instance = serializer.save(author=self.request.user)
    return super(ProjectViewSet, self).perform_create(serializer)
```