# Issues in fetching List of related objects in Serilazier

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I have two models like :

```
class Car(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)

class CarImage(models.Model):
    car = models.ForeignKey(Car, related_name='photos')
    photo = models.ImageField(upload_to='car/')
```

From above models I wanted to fetch all images of car. So I write my serailzer as follows :

```
class CarSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    """
    """
    _id = serializers.ReadOnlyField(source='pk')

    photos = serializers.RelatedField(many=True, read_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Car
        fields = ('my_field_here', )

class CarImageSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    """

    """
    _id = serializers.ReadOnlyField(source='pk')

    class Meta:
        model = CarImage
        fields = ('my_field_here', )
```

But in `CarSerializer` serializer photos field is giving this error `RelatedField.to_representation() must be implemented for field . If you do not need to support write operations you probably want to subclass`ReadOnlyField`instead.`
But id I use `PrimaryKeyRelatedField` instead of RelatedField then its working fine and I am getting list of primary key but I want all fields.

I also tried to use `CarImageSerializer` as

In `Carserializer` decalared

```
assets_keys = serializers.SerializerMethodField()
def get_assets_keys(self, obj):
    return AssetKeySerializer(obj.asset_keys.all(), context=self.context).data
```

But it can't serialize list of asset keys , it needs single object.

So my question is is it possible to get related objects data using serializers. If yes, what I need to correct in my serializers ?

My response must be looks like :

```
[
  {
    "_id": 1,
    "name": "first",
    "photos": [
      "name":"xyz",
      "photo":"path_to_photo"
    ]
  },
   {
    "_id": 1,
    "name": "second",
    "photos": [
      "name":"abcddd",
      "photo":"path_to_photo"
    ]
  },
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use [nested serializer](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/#nested-relationships) in `CarSerializer`:

```
photos = CarImageSerializer(many=True, read_only=True)
```

Comment: Yes, i figured that out after some time, initially I was not using Many=True, just one more question , I can use the same serializer for POST & PUT too right ?

Comment: By Default nested serializers are read only. For more detail you can look at my another answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/36299894/2549021).