# Django (DRF): Serialize and deserialize a ManyToMany field differently?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

Getting used to Django Rest Framework coming over from Tastypie, but am having a problem when it comes to ManyToMany fields.

When the field needs to be serialized its preferred to include its complete representation and this is easily done by adding a ModelSerializer with many=True and read_only=True. The problem is this prevents me from saving the account field as it now appears blank.

If I try removing read_only=True I get

```
TypeError: 'accounts' is an invalid keyword argument for this function
```

It's best to send the full representation but only require the ID when receiving a related POST (create) or PUT (update).

POST:

```
{
    "profile" : "1",
    "accounts" : ["1"],
    "amount" : "101.00"
}
```

RESPONSE:

```
{
  "id": 92,
  "accounts": [],
  "date_by": null,
  "amount": "101.00",
  "shared": false,
  "profile": 1
}
```

GET:

```
[
  {
    "id": 45,
    "accounts": [
      {
        "account_local": {
          "id": 3,
          "last_balance": "100.00",
        },
        "type": "LocalAccount"
      }
    ],
    "date_by": null,
    "amount": "100.00",
    "shared": false,
    "profile": 1
  },]
```

GoalSerializer

```
class GoalSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    accounts = AccountSerializer(many=True, read_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Goal
```

GoalViewSet

```
class GoalViewSet(GenericViewSet, mixins.RetrieveModelMixin, mixins.ListModelMixin, mixins.CreateModelMixin):
    serializer_class = GoalSerializer
    queryset = Goal.objects.none()

    def get_queryset(self):
        return Goal.objects.filter(profile=self.request.user)
```

AccountSerializer

```
class AccountSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    type = SerializerMethodField('get_account_class')

    class Meta:
        model = Account
        fields = ('account_local','account_external', 'type')
        depth = 1

    def get_account_class(self, obj):
        if isinstance(obj.get_actual(), LocalAccount):
            return obj.get_actual().__class__.__name__
        elif isinstance(obj.get_actual(), ExternalAccount):
            return obj.get_actual().get_actual().__class__.__name__
        else:
            return "Error"

    def to_representation(self, instance):
        data = super(AccountSerializer, self).to_representation(instance)

        if isinstance(instance.get_actual(), ExternalAccount): 
            serializer = ExternalAccountSerializerEMT(instance.account_external.get_actual())
            data['account_external'] = serializer.data

        return data
```

Comment: Please have a look at my other answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/36299894/2549021).

Answer (score 1):

I managed to get around this by:

- Changing **AccountSerializer** with a

  `def to_internal_value(self, data):
      return Account.objects.get(id=data)`
- Removing the read_only attribute on the field

  `accounts = AccountSerializer(many=True)`

The account only needs to be an id when POST'ing / PUT'ing and the whole account is returned when GET'ing

Comment: I did have to add protection to make sure the Account's are actually owned by the Profile, but beyond that...